# Projection Of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning about projections of matrices in Linear Algebra and one of the  home work questions is: Determine the matrix [$\text{proj}_v $] given v is \begin{pmatrix}
     -2 \\
     1
     \end{pmatrix}
I am kind of confused as to what it means because a projection normally consists of 2 vectors e.g. finding the projection of y onto x. 
So if someone could help me understand what the question is asking that would be great!!

Comment: Yes, the vector projection of **what** vector onto **what** subspace?  You could interpret this as asking for the projection of the vector <-2, 1> onto some subspace, but what subspace?  Or it could be asking for the projection or some other vector onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by <-2, 1> but what other vector?  I suspect there is more to this problem than you have told us.

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{proj}_v$ stands for projection onto the subspace spanned by $v$, so the problem is asking you to find a general formula (i.e., a matrix) for the projection of _any_ vector onto this subspace.

Comment: Take a vector w={x,y}, find p=projection of w on v. Express the result as a matrix M such that p=Mw